# iPhone App does not work in iOS 4.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Please help.  iPhone App does not work in iOS 4.1 , but works fine in iOS 5 and iOS 6. I have integrated Facebook and Twitter APIs in this app. I have built the app in Xcode 4.3. Please help.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You'll need to provide more details.

Comment: Does it need to work on 4.1?  Right now that's a pretty small group of people.  If you factor in the effort to make your code backwards compatible and compare that to the expected return you'll get for the very tiny group of users you'll now support it may not be worth it.

Comment: iOS 4.1 doesn't support Twitter API

Comment: @Dancreek is right, there is really no reason to support 4.1 unless you ABSOLUTELY have to. I want to say I read an article recently that 95% of iphone users are ios 5.0+ (that was pre-ios6) but I can't find it. I'll update when I do.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to set all the ios5/6 libraries (like social.framework, Accounts.framework,etc..) as optional in "Build Phases" since these are not available in ios4.3.

Click on your project->select your target in the main window->select build phases tab-> look in "Link Binary with Libraries" section.

Also please provide more info on the error as Simon said.

Comment: When application is clicked, it just does not open up. It has to atleast come to the splash screen. I have included all the libraries. Please let me know the issue

Comment: @Alexey , is it sure that iOS 4.1 doesn't support Twitter API  ??

Comment: you have to configure the ios5/6 libraries as "optional". iOS twitter integration was introduced in ios5.

Comment: I have used, Twitter framework and used the option ShareOn part to tweet and to post in facebook.